# Fire Default Button on jTextField Action Performed

Tags: java, swing, defaultbutton

In my program have a `JButton` and `JTextField`.
I want jButton fire while press Enter key in `JTextField`
I'm not talking about `KeyEvent`.

```
private void jTextFieldActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                            
    this.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(jButton1);
}
```

This just make `JButton` focus enabled after enter in `JTextField`
So when I will enter in JTextField it must fire `JButton` ActionEvent.

And have this code on `jButton1` `ActionPerformed` method.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Hi!");
    }
```

So how can I make `JButton` fired on `JTextField` `ActionEvent`?
I tried following answer but in IDE it throwing exception.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.swing.JButton.addActionListener
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve that (if i got this straight), is to add an `ActionListener` to the JTextField which will call `JButton#doClick()` method. (I think it is pretty clear what the `doClick()` method does).

An example:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class FireButtonOnEnter extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7346953935931623335L;

    public FireButtonOnEnter() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(400, 400);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(15);
        JButton button = new JButton("Print Hello");
        button.addActionListener(e -> System.out.println("Hello world."));
        textField.addActionListener(e -> button.doClick());
        getContentPane().add(textField);
        getContentPane().add(button);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> new FireButtonOnEnter().setVisible(true));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should NOT call `getRootPane().setDefaultButton(jButton1);` inside the `ActionListener` of text field (actually you don't need an `ActionListener` for text field).

You should call `getRootPane().setDefaultButton(jButton1);` in UI initialization.

`setDefaultButton(jButton1)` is NOT there to "fire" the Enter key event. It is there to "specify" that you want `jButton1` to be the "default" button.

See below demonstration.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;

public class DefaultButton {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JButton button = new JButton("Button 1");
    button.addActionListener(DefaultButton::jButton1ActionPerformed);

    JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);

    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.getContentPane().add(button);
    frame.getContentPane().add(textField);

    frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button);

    frame.setBounds(300, 200, 400, 300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }

  private static void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hi!");
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

If you don't want to make `button` the default button and you just want to show the message dialog when user hits Enter key, then you can call the same `jButton1ActionPerformed()` from an ActionListener of the text field like this:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(20);
textField.addActionListener(DefaultButton::jButton1ActionPerformed);
```

And remove this line:

```
frame.getRootPane().setDefaultButton(button);
```

Comment: Your answer is more suitable than others but I'm not able to implement in NetBeans IDE.

Comment: Cause I used drag and drop.

Comment: @SwapnilNagtilak, UI builders in IDEs are ok to build simple UIs and to only build the initial structure of UIs. Beyond that, we need manual UI coding skills. Without that our UIs will not be optimal.

Comment: Hi, it solved using `jTextField1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(e);
            }
        });`